# PHP include with ../ failed open

Tags: php

I am trying to include a php file from the parent directory and I getting error:

> admin@webby:~$ /usr/bin/php
>   /var/phpscripts/email_parser/tests/_email-test.php PHP Fatal error: 
>   require_once(): Failed opening required '../PlancakeEmailParser.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /var/phpscripts/email_parser/tests/_email-test.php on line 6
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '../PlancakeEmailParser.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /var/phpscripts/email_parser/tests/_email-test.php on line 6

PHP file

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^E_WARNING);
ini_set("display_errors" , 1);

require_once("../PlancakeEmailParser.php");

// etc

?>
```

Folder Structure

```
admin@webby:/var/phpscripts/email_parser$ find .
.
./composer.json
./README.txt
./LICENSE.txt
./PlancakeEmailParser.php
./tests
./tests/_email-test.php
```

For testing it works fine when I move `PlancakeEmailParser.php` into the `tests` directory and remove the "../" from the require

Comment: Try doing it this way: `require_once(__DIR__."/../PlancakeEmailParser.php");`

Comment: @hakre: how come relative include do not work when calling a php script from command line

Comment: @JohnMagnolia: They work, but the question is to which base path are they relative too and which one is the current base path PHP uses to resolve them? (Working directory differs) - the other point is PHP's configuration for the include path directive. (php configuration differs) - That are merely the two points I can imagine. Provide the [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/getcwd) and the value of the setting: `var_dump(getcwd(), get_include_path());` to explain this better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
require_once("../PlancakeEmailParser.php");
```

Is not using a fully qualified file-system path or PHP-URI-scheme. Therefore its outcome depends on PHP configuration, most often because of the [include directory configuration](http://php.net/ini.core#ini.include-path).

The PHP CLI can use a different configuration file than with your webserver *- or -* the working directory is different as with your webserver (probably the later plays more of a role in your specific scenario).

What you want can be easily expressed fully qualified, too:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . "/../PlancakeEmailParser.php");
```

This is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Thats worked thanks. This is my first php script called from command line looks like there are quite a few of these instances where it works different to a standard file inside of the /var/www

Comment: Are there any guides/articles which lists the most common issues that I am likely to run into issues like this

Comment: Not that I especially know of on top of my head, however, I usually use this `__DIR__` special constant. This won't make PHP search a lot *and* it's clear what it does *and* it works everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [PHP CLI SAPI: Differences to other SAPIs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php):

> It does not change the working directory to that of the script. (-C
>   and --no-chdir switches kept for compatibility)

In order to keep relative paths in your script working as-is, change directory to where the script resides, then execute the script:

```
cd /var/phpscripts/email_parser/tests/ && ./_email-test.php
```